# Opening a file with specific extension in Firefox

Tags: linux, apache, firefox

I have a file to download with .hede extension. How can I force Firefox to open it with a script located in `/usr/bin`? This *.hede file contains text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From apache you can't tell a browser how to handle a certain type of file, unless it's some commonly used mime-type/application mapping. Your best bet may be to create yourself a mime-type by using [`AddType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype), something like:

```
AddType application/hede  .hede
```

When someone uses something like Firefox to open your file with the hede extension, they'll get a window that asks how they should handle the `application/hede` mime-type, they can then browse and select the script located in /usr/bin.